# How properties from the external file could be loaded into T-SQL procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have T-SQL stored procedure doing some data processing. For some unprocessed values it should still fill the table with the values set beforehand. For example, 'N/A' or 'Unprocessed'.

```
declare @nA varchar(100)
set @nA = 'N/A' 
... 
... 
update #temptable
set someField = @nA
where...
```

I store these values in the procedure itself but I want to have that values at the external file. Could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BULK INSERT` to read data from the file:

```
CREATE TABLE #tablename
(col1 VARCHAR(100))

BULK INSERT #tablename FROM 'D:\value.txt' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR ='|' )

declare @nA varchar(100)
SELECT @nA = col1 FROM #tablename

DROP TABLE #tablename

update #temptable
set someField = @nA
where...
```